# Find distribution function for $P(X\leq x)=1-1/(1-x)$ with transform a+bX

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I my homework I have to show that for a random variable $X$ with distribution function $P(X\leq x)=1-\frac{1}{1+x}$ for $x>0$ and 0 everywhere else,

then the transform $h=a+bX, \, a,b\in \mathbb{R}, \, b>0$ is
$P(a+bX \leq x)=1-\frac{b}{b-a+x}$ for $x\geq a$

To solve show it I tried using the transformation formula $f(h^{-1})\cdot|h'^{-1}|$

with $h^{-1}=\frac{y-a}{b}$ and $h'^{-1}=\frac{1}{b}$

However this gives me $(1-b-(b-a+x)) \cdot |\frac{1}{b}|$ where the last term is wrong

I cannot find the error, any help would be appreciated

Comment: This is not a valid distribution function.

Comment: Note that $P(X\leq 1/2) = 1-1/(1-1/2)=-1$. I can't make sense of it.

Comment: Maybe $1 - \frac{1}{1+x}$ ?

Comment: it was a typo - fixed now, thanks for noticing

Comment: I think you are using the formula for the pdf and not cdf. You can note that $\Pr(a + bX \leq x) = \Pr(X \leq (x-a)/b) = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + (x-a)/b} = 1 - \frac{b}{b - a + x}$ as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula does not seem to be correct.

Let $g$ be an increasing bijection, and $H=g(X)$

$$F_H(h)=P(H\leq h)=P(g(X) \leq h)=P(X \leq g^{-1}(h))=F_X(g^{-1}(h))$$

$f_H(h)=F_H'(h)=F_X'(g^{-1}(h))*(g^{-1})'(h)=f_X(g^{-1}(h))\frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(h))}$

In your case $g(x)=bx+a$, $g^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-a}{b}$

Therefore,
$f_H(x)=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{x-a}{b}\right)^2}*\frac{1}{b(\frac{x-a}{b})}$ with $x \geq a$